# How to tie JSON schema with JSON data

Tags: json, json.net, schema

I understand that we can define Schema for a JSON structure, but I'm unable to find any info on how to tie the schema with actual json data, where exactly within JSON data we mention the schema for the JSON.

I'm trying to understand how I can return a JSON data along with the Schema so that the end user/service that consumes my JSON can discover and understand the schema associated with the json data.

Comment: It depends on your application needs. There are several validators that are mentioned here depending on the programming language: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html

Comment: Thanks, I understand the availability of validators, I'm trying to understand how I can declare the schema of my JSON to consumers? Is there a way to embed the reference (uri) of schema within JSON? if not any other way?

Comment: I don't think there are any standard ways to publish your schema in terms of a specific location.